# Do I need to change my ESTA address when visiting the US?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta

I have an ESTA for my visit last Sept to NY and I know it is valid for 2years.  I am going to Las Vegas in May, do I have to update the address at which I will be staying?

Answer (score 20):

No, you don't have to do so.

The official line, from the [CBP FAQ page on the VWP and ESTA](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel):

> **Q:**
>   Can prospective travelers apply for an ESTA without specific travel
>   plans if they want to be able to travel to the United States later on
>   short notice?
>
> **A:**
>   Yes. VWP travelers are not required to have specific plans to travel
>   to the United States before they apply for an ESTA. If a traveler’s
>   destination in the United States is unknown when he or she completes
>   the ESTA application, the traveler should enter “Unknown.” **Travelers
>   may update this information when their plans are finalized, but they
>   will not be required to update their destination addresses or
>   itineraries should they change after their ESTA application has been
>   approved.** DHS recommends that ESTA applications be submitted as early
>   as possible, as soon as, or even before travel is planned. ESTA will
>   accept applications from last-minute and emergency travelers – those
>   VWP travelers who arrive at the airport without an approved ESTA.

Comment: I am making an ESTA application right now and had a similar question: I have booked flights, but haven't booked accommodation yet. I was wondering if there was any downside to putting "unknown" in the address field (like, it might look "suspicious"!)... This answer re-assures me that it perfectly normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In my personal experience no. I've been to the US three times staying in different locations without altering the address. Although full disclosure, I'm not sure if that's ok, it is my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question a few weeks ago, but no. It doesn't matter, as long as you have your ESTA and it's valid, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I know a Norwegian who was detained in secondary twice for failing to update his address.

As such, while it's not required, you should update it as soon as you know the new address.