# Update ESTA information?

Tags: usa, esta

Even though that is probably not necessary (as answered in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45832/do-i-need-to-change-my-esta-address-when-visiting-the-us)), I updated the US address where I will be staying for my second stay in the US after the ESTA application. Now, there also is a field for a US contact person, where I had listed the hotel of my first stay, but using the "update" option of the official ESTA application page, there does not seem any way to update this. Should I take any additional steps to update this information as well?